# Why is this Grails (GORM) Query invalid?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following domain models in Grails I am trying to run a query against, but it is failing, saying it is an invalid query.

The query looks like:

> ```
>   StringBuilder queryBuf = new StringBuilder();
>     queryBuf.append("select rr.role from ReportRole rr ");
>     def newroles = ReportRole.findAll(queryBuf)
> ```

And, the domains look like this:

```
package auth

import java.util.Date
import auth.Report
import auth.Role

class ReportRole {
Long id
Report report
Role role
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
Person createdBy

static mapping = {
    table 'CIT_RM_Report_Role'
    version false
    role joinTable:[name:'AU_ROLE_DESCR', key:'role_id', column:'id']
    columns {
        id column:'report_role_id'
        report column:'report_id'
        createdBy column:'created_by'
        dateCreated column:'create_date'
        lastUpdated column:'last_updated'

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package auth;
class Role {
static hasMany = [people: Person]
Long id;
String authority;
String description;
static mapping = {
    table 'AU_ROLE_DESCR'
    people joinTable:[name:'AU_PERSON_ROLE', key:'AUTHORITY_ID', column:'PERSON_ID']
    version false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is invalid.  I have some similar domains where a query like this will work.

Comment: Exact error is: Invalid query [select rr.role from ReportRole rr] for domain class [class auth.ReportRole]

Comment: I thought I may have had the key/column mixed up, so I tried reversing them, but same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose `findAll` is restricted to get back with a list of domain instead of any association/element in particular. You can better use `executeQuery` to achieve what you seek:

```
ReportRole.executeQuery("select rr.role from ReportRole rr")
```